# Exception while trying to display MahApps Metro Dialog

Tags: wpf, dialog, mahapps.metro

When calling this function 
`await this.ShowMessageAsync("Title","Message")` I receive a NullReferenceException that comes from the line `MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle in C:\projects\mahapps-metro\src\MahApps.Metro\ThemeManager\ThemeManager.cs:line 540`

edit: 
`<ResourceDictionary "...Colors.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary "...Controls.xaml"/>
<ResourceDictionary "...Accents/blue.xaml"/>`